# How to select data by comparing two items names and its dates in a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

So im trying to get a item "Like" from a table only if the date is more recent then the item "Dislike" with the same userID. Sometimes it may only be a "Like" there and then that should always be selected too.

This is what i have so far that works:

```
$query = "
SELECT * 
  FROM useractions 
 WHERE userid = '$userID' 
   AND (action= 'Like' OR action='Dislike')
 ";
```

There i get all the Like/Dislike from the same userid. Now i just need to compare it with "date" to see if "Like" is a more recent date than "Dislike" and if so, select it and also see that the like/dislike is working on the same object.

So what i was writing out (without it working obviously) is an additional `AND` to my query.

```
AND (action='Like' date > action='Dislike' date)"
```

(date is another item in my table with a date).

This does not work of course. How would I need to adjust it in order to make it a valid SQL query?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I would suggest that you make use of `NOT EXISTS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a join between the two subquery

```
    select t1.* from  
    (
    select * 
    FROM useractions 
    WHERE userid = '$userID'   
    AND action= 'Like' 
    ) t1 
    inner join  (
    select * 
    FROM useractions 
    WHERE userid = '$userID'   
    AND action='Dislike'
    ) t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid and t1.date > t2.date 
    where t1.userid = '$userID'
```

anyway you should not use php var in sql  .. take a look at you php mysql driver  for prepared statement and binding param

Comment: what if i also need to add that they both must have the same "objectid"? this objectid is not sent in. its a value in the table that we pick from

Comment: you can simple add the condition in the join clause  .. `t1.userid = t2.userid and t1.obejctid = t2.objectid and t1.date > t2.date `

Comment: oh sorry, let me rephrase. if they have the same objectid, then i want this query to be executed so only show likes if it was "like" more recent than "dislike" on the same objectid. if a like has been made on a objectid and a dislike has not been made on the same objectid, then that like should be be selected.

Comment: your comment is difficult to uderstand for me  .. you should add  a new question  .. properly described  and with a clear data sample  .. when  you have done  you can comment me the link for the new question ..in this way all the SO community can hellp you  ..

Comment: this is hard to explain :((

Comment: So first i send my userid. Then I need to see if the object (objected) that is liked that I found has been disliked too by the same userid. If it has then we need to see 1. Was it disliked more recent? Then we should not select this object. If we then find a liked object that has never been disliked by the same userid, we should select it, and lastly if we found an object that has been liked and disliked by the same userid, but the liked is more recent, it should be selected.

Comment: does that make sense?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52709205/how-to-sele @scaisEdge there

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez . . . You accepted this answer and it has no reference to `objectid` -- which is the specific comment you left on my answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff move that answer to my new post, i will readjust this one to the original question and accept his answer on this one, and ur answer on the new one. ok?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `not exists`:

```
SELECT ua.*
FROM useractions ua
WHERE ua.userid = '$userID' AND ua.action ='Like' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM useractions ua2
                  WHERE ua2.userid = ua.userid AND
                        ua2.action = 'dislike' AND
                        ua2.date > ua.date
                );
```

For performance, you want an index on `useractions(userid, action, date)`.

For the same object, you would just do:

```
SELECT ua.*
FROM useractions ua
WHERE ua.userid = '$userID' AND ua.action ='Like' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM useractions ua2
                  WHERE ua2.userid = ua.userid AND
                        ua2.objectid = ua.objectid AND
                        ua2.action = 'dislike' AND
                        ua2.date > ua.date
                );
```

Comment: Alright just tried this. One thing. Like and dislike has to be targetting the same objectid. So if the userid is 5 for both a dislike and like, we have to see if they are targetting the same objectid.

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez . . . Then include `objectid` in the correlation clause (this really is not clear in your question).